# Android communication, what is sent is not what is received

Tags: android, sockets, serial-port, arduino

Moved from Android forums

Im at a loss here. It want to send some serial data from arduino to android but what I send is not what is received. For example, If I put Serial.write(5), on the android side I get 48. If I put Serial.write(6) I get 1. The same problem happens when I send characters. If I send a 't', on android I get a T with 2 points on top(as if its a character from another language). ??????? What's happening?

Arduino

```
int count = 5;
const unsigned int BAUD_RATE = 115200;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
 delay(10000);
}

void loop() {
  //Serial.print(count, DEC);
  //Serial.print(count, HEX);
  Serial.print(count, OCT);
  //Serial.println(count, BIN);
  //Serial.write(temp);
  //Serial.write("t");
  Serial.write(count);
  count++;
  delay(2000);
}
```

Android
RFComm: UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
Handler myHandler1 = new Handler();
Runnable receiveValues = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (connected) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    Log.v("Note",
                            "For value: " + String.valueOf(in.read(buffer)));
                    for (int x = 0; x < buffer.length; x++)
                        Log.v("Note", "A " + buffer[x]);
                }
                Thread.sleep(50);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connected = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};
```

The timing is right, every two seconds something gets sent but still I get the wrong value. As you can also see, I tried other ways to write to the serial port on the arduino but none of them work. Another thing, the end of line(when I do Serial.println()) is consistently received as a 0 on android.

Running on android 2.3.7 where min sdk = 8 (android 2.2)

Comment: Are you sure the baud rate. parity and stop bits are matched? The garbage you are seeing is typical of a mismatch.

Comment: Yep, the baud rate is right, but the int is not(see my answer). Thanks for your comment, it sent me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is really simple... Forgot about int ranges(-32768 to +32767) or in this case unsigned int(0 - 65534) and when I directly entered the baud rate, it worked well.

```
Serial.begin(115200);
```